# debhelper: add `prefix=/usr' to all implicit make invocations

Tags: makefile, debian, debhelper

I have a `Makefile` that starts with

```
prefix      = /opt/$(PACKAGE)
```

and expects `make prefix=/usr` in case someone wants a non-`/opt` installation. There's no `./configure` (and no need for one really).

The package is trivially debianizable via

```
%:
        dh $@
```

as `debian/rules` except that, due to the `prefix=/usr` requirement, one would have to litter the rules with

```
override_dh_auto_install:
        make prefix=/usr DESTDIR=debian/BUILD install
```

(also `dh_auto_build`).

What is the elegant way to tell debhelper to add a `prefix=` to all `make` invocations (preferably without touching the makefile, otherwise there are many workarounds)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
%:
    prefix=/usr dh $@
```

This works because make converts environment variable into make variables, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html

Just make sure that you upstream Makefile uses conditional assignment like in:

```
prefix ?= /usr/local
```

Ciao,
   Antonio

Answer (score 0):

Does exporting `MAKEFLAGS=prefix=/usr` in your rules file (or wherever that trivial snippet lives) do what you want?

Comment: It doesn't work. I think dh "sanitizes" MAKEFLAGS. Strangely, if I add `echo "$$MAKEFLAGS"` to my all: target, it seems the flags are "w" (a single char)

Comment: Hm... so something is stomping over your MAKEFLAGS then. I saw reference to mangling MAKEFLAGS with regard to -j but nothing more general than that. I doubt it will but you could try and see if 'dh $@ -O=prefix=/usr' (or however that syntax needs to work exactly) works?

Comment: Neither `-O prefix=/usr` nor `-O=prefix=/usr` work, and I don't know "however that syntax needs to work" :) -O doesn't seem to be documented

Comment: It is a debhelper option. From `[debhelper options]` in the dh man page. But I'm trying to put pieces together that I don't have any real knowledge of at this point. Sorry.